# VB Express 2013 - My own form class is empty

Tags: vb.net, forms, desktop-application

I´m creating desktop app. I tried to create my own form class like this:

```
Public Class TMyForm
Inherits Form

Protected ThisForm As Form
Protected IsOpened As Boolean
Protected Mode As FormMode
Enum FormMode
    Gmail
    Twitter
End Enum

Public Sub New(ByVal Form As Form)
    Me.ThisForm = Form
End Sub

Public Sub SetUI(ByVal LoginTo As String)

    If LoginTo Is Nothing Then
        Me.IsOpened = False
        Me.Close()
    Else
        Me.IsOpened = True
        Select Case LoginTo
            Case "Gmail"
                Mode = FormMode.Gmail
                Me.Text = "Gmail login"
            Case "Twitter"
                Mode = FormMode.Twitter
        End Select

    End If

End Sub
End Class
```

Now I would like to call this from my main form:

```
Public Class SideBlock

Protected LoginForm As New LoginForm

Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

    SetLayout()

End Sub

Private Sub GmailToolStripMenuItem_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles GmailToolStripMenuItem.Click
    Dim LoginForm As New TMyForm(Me.LoginForm)
    LoginForm.SetUI("Gmail")
    LoginForm.Show()
End Sub
End Class
```

As you can see I call my TMyForm class with existing form called LoginForm. After clicking on the Gmail button the login form appears but its epmpty. There should be textboxs etc. But all I see is empty form.

Did I missed something? Thank you

Comment: It looks like you are downcasting.  `TMyForm` may have controls on it, but with `Sub New(ByVal Form As Form)` a generic form is received with no controls etc on it.  Kind of hard to tell what you are trying to accomplish

Comment: No TMyForm has no controls, Form as Form (input of that) has cnotrols

Comment: The `Type` you are passing, `System.Windows.Forms.Form` is the base type for all forms.  It has no controls.  You might *send* type `TMyForm` but `As Form` casts it to `System.Windows.Forms.Form` which...has no controls or custom methods in it.

Comment: Im sry but I dont uderstand what do you mean. TMyForm is just extended Form class. Form I need to show is LoginForm that one has all controls.

Comment: you said yourself that your TMyForm has no control so obviously when you `Show` it's empty !

Comment: Forms are classes.  When you design a new form, you are designing a new `Type`.  `TMyForm` is one `Type`, `LoginForm` is another `Type`.  Both inherit from `System.Windows.Forms.Form`.  Change your `Sub New` to `As LogInForm` and maybe you will see what is going on.

Comment: I added this to TMyForm:

        Public Overloads Sub Show()
        Me.ThisForm.Show()
        End Sub

This work, is that correctly used?

Comment: probably not ; I don't even understand why TMyForm inherits from Form if it's not intended to BE a Form but rather OWN a Form ; Make your class a "regular" class which owns a Form or make your class a real Form descendant with custom controls and all and call it directly (maybe passing argument to it's constructor related to the display mode)

Comment: Yes it seems to be kind of pointless when I look at it now. Im still new to this. Thanks for answers I learned something new today